# Не работает расширение

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

```
function reload1() {
if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('XXXXXXXXXX.COM') > -1) 
{ 
function SaveToFile() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({reminds: inspect1}, 
        function () {
var inspect1 = document.querySelector('.item-inspect').href; // ПОЛУЧИТЬ ИНСПЕКТ ЛИНК
 });
} 
}

if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('FFFFFFFFFF.NET') > -1)
{
function LoadFromFile() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('reminds', function (results) { 
    console.log(results.reminds);
    });
}
} 
}

setInterval(reload1, 8000);
```

С первого сайта я парсю ссылку, на втором пытаюсь вывести её в консоль ( для проверки работоспособности хранилища). Собственно весь код, в манифесте "storage" указал. На конечном сайте консоль остается пустой , даже ошибок нет. `console.log(results.reminds);`Сайты не связаны

**UPD**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Skin",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
  "storage",
  "tabs",
  "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
     "<all_urls>"
   ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]


    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"

  }

}
```

В background ничего не указано, расширение работает с только с контент скриптом

Comment: Что это за код? `content-script`? В какой момент он запускатеся? В манифесте указаны права на сайты? К сожалению вы предоставили недостаточно информации

Comment: @Deliaz обновил

Comment: Конечный код в одном файле https://pastebin.com/nDwcpwFW

Answer (score 0):

Вызывая функцию **`reload1()`**, вы по условию **`if`** декларируете одну из функций - **`SaveToFile()`** либо **`LoadFromFile()`**. Однако вызова этих функций не происходит, вызывается только сама **`reload1()`** с интервалом.

```
function reload1() {
    if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('XXXXXXXXXX.COM') > -1) { 
        function SaveToFile() {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({reminds: inspect1}, function () {
                var inspect1 = document.querySelector('.item-inspect').href; // ПОЛУЧИТЬ ИНСПЕКТ ЛИНК
            });
        } 
    }

    if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('FFFFFFFFFF.NET') > -1){
        function LoadFromFile() {
            chrome.storage.sync.get('reminds', function (results) { 
                console.log(results.reminds);
            });
        }
    } 
}

setInterval(reload1, 8000);
```

Либо добавляйте вызов функций и описание отдельно, либо делайте их анонимными, либо вообще не оборачивайте функциями (в вашем случае оптимально):

```
// вариант уно, без вложенных функция:
function reload1() {
    if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('XXXXXXXXXX.COM') > -1) { 
        chrome.storage.sync.set({reminds: inspect1}, function () {
           ...

// вариант дуос, описание функции и вызов отдельно:
function SaveToFile(data) {
            ...
});
function reload1() {
    if (document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('XXXXXXXXXX.COM') > -1) { 
        SaveToFile(data);  
    }
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7UZSuq31 // `Uncaught ReferenceError: inspect1 is not defined
    at SaveToFile (content.js:2)
    at reload1 (content.js:18)`
Вроде сделал как и сказали